# inventory file variables are not calling by with_items in ansible Zypper module

Tags: azure, ansible

I have a inventory file with below details.This pkgs-list should be call by ansible module in main.yml.But its not calling.What am i doing wrong here?

```
[target:vars]
pkgs_list = vim cloudnetconfig
```

Main.yml has below module

```
- name: Install all packages 
   zypper:
     name:"{{ item }}"
     state:present
  with_items: '{{ pkgs_list }}"
```

error says "No provider found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've made `pkgs_list` a string. To use compose data types (dicts and lists) it's better to use yaml inventory.

inventory.yaml

```
target:
  hosts:
    example:
  vars:
   pkgs_list: [vim, cloudnetconfig]
```